# Is it possible use a jquery variable value as a key in dot notation javascript to find and array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Im trying to use a jQuery variable in dot notation javascript to retrieve a value from a multidimensional JSON array

```
var products = {
  "p1": {
    "price":"12.98"
  },
  "p2": {
    "price":"9.98"
  }
}

var pid = $(this).attr('id');
//console returns p1

var price = products.pid.price;
console.log(price);
//console returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
```

I suspect this is due to me passing a value in as a key or something but can't get my head around it all.  Or it could be a string when it needs to be something else.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `pid` is a string, not a jQuery object.

Comment: use `products[pid].price` instead.

Comment: You need bracket notation, not dot notation.